# Unstack Groupby does not group the data in proper dataset using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Hello Data Scientist and Pandas Experts,

I need some help as I can’t get my data organized properly.

When using unstack in groupby it does not group the data in properly.
Here is my dataframe:

```
data = [
{'Store': 'Store1', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'aemp', 'Department': 'dep1'},\
{'Store': 'Store1', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-07 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'aemp', 'Department': 'dep1'},\
{'Store': 'Store1', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'bemp', 'Department': 'dep1'},\
{'Store': 'Store1', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-07 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'bemp', 'Department': 'dep1'},\
{'Store': 'Store1', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'cemp', 'Department': 'dep2'},\
{'Store': 'Store1', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'demp', 'Department': 'dep2'},\
{'Store': 'Store1', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'demp', 'Department': 'dep2'},\
{'Store': 'Store1', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'cemp', 'Department': 'dep2'},\
{'Store': 'Store1', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'demp', 'Department': 'dep2'},\
{'Store': 'Store1', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-07 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'demp', 'Department': 'dep2'},\
{'Store': 'Store1', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-07 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'demp', 'Department': 'dep2'},\
{'Store': 'Store1', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-07 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'demp', 'Department': 'dep2'},\
{'Store': 'Store1', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-07 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'demp', 'Department': 'dep2'},\
{'Store': 'Store2', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'eemp', 'Department': 'dep1'},\
{'Store': 'Store2', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-07 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'eemp', 'Department': 'dep1'},\
{'Store': 'Store2', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'femp', 'Department': 'dep1'},\
{'Store': 'Store2', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-07 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'eemp', 'Department': 'dep1'},\
{'Store': 'Store2', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'femp', 'Department': 'dep1'},\
{'Store': 'Store2', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-07 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'femp', 'Department': 'dep1'},\
{'Store': 'Store2', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'aemp', 'Department': 'dep1'},\
{'Store': 'Store2', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-07 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'aemp', 'Department': 'dep1'},\
{'Store': 'Store2', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'demp', 'Department': 'dep2'},\
{'Store': 'Store2', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'gemp', 'Department': 'dep2'},\
{'Store': 'Store2', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-07 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'demp', 'Department': 'dep2'},\
{'Store': 'Store2', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-05 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'gemp', 'Department': 'dep2'},\
{'Store': 'Store2', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-07 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'gemp', 'Department': 'dep2'},\
{'Store': 'Store2', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-09 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'cemp', 'Department': 'dep2'},\
{'Store': 'Store3', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'eemp', 'Department': 'dep1'},\
{'Store': 'Store3', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-05 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'eemp', 'Department': 'dep1'},\
{'Store': 'Store3', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'bemp', 'Department': 'dep1'},\
{'Store': 'Store3', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-05 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'bemp', 'Department': 'dep1'},\
{'Store': 'Store3', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'bemp', 'Department': 'dep1'},\
{'Store': 'Store3', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-07 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'demp', 'Department': 'dep2'},\
{'Store': 'Store3', 'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00'), 'Employee': 'demp', 'Department': 'dep2'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to organize my output as follow:

```
 Store        Store1                   Store2                            Store3           
 Department   dep1          dep2       dep1           dep2             dep1      dep2   
 Employee      aemp  bemp  cemp demp   aemp eemp femp cemp demp gemp   bemp eemp demp
 Date
 2020-08-03    1.0   1.0   2.0  3.0    1.0  1.0  2.0   0.0  1.0 1.0    2.0  1.0   1.0
 2020-08-10    1.0   1.0   0.0  4.0    1.0  2.0  1.0   1.0  2.0 1.0    1.0  1.0   1.0
```

I used following groupby expression (I don't know how to sort the frame by its level):

```
df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='W-MON'), 'Store', 'Department', 'Employee'])\
       .size().unstack(['Store', 'Department', 'Employee']).fillna(0)
```

Here is what I got the result when I used above groupby expression:

```
Store      Store1                Store2                     Store3           Store2
Department   dep1      dep2        dep1           dep2        dep1      dep2   dep2
Employee     aemp bemp cemp demp   aemp eemp femp demp gemp   bemp eemp demp   cemp
Date
2020-08-03    1.0  1.0  2.0  3.0    1.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  1.0    2.0  1.0  1.0    0.0
2020-08-10    1.0  1.0  0.0  4.0    1.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  2.0    1.0  1.0  1.0    1.0
```

Please provide me your expert help on how I can solve and fix my output so everything group properly.

Thank You and really appreciate your help.

This is continuous of my previous blog: [How to show only column with Values in Pandas Groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64487049/how-to-show-only-column-with-values-in-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there, you just need to:

1. Change the order of your `.groupby` columns as it will unstack in order and `date` needs to be at the end rather than the beginning OR
2. You can sort by the index, but rearranging correctly in step 1 prevents you from having to do this extra step.

---

Rearranging `.groupby` columns:

```
df = (df.groupby(['Store', 'Department', 'Employee', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='W-MON'), ])
        .size()
        .unstack(['Store', 'Department', 'Employee']).fillna(0))
```

---

OR  sort by the index, prior to unstacking with `sort_index()`:

```
df = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='W-MON'), 'Store', 'Department', 'Employee'])
        .size()
        .sort_index(level=['Store', 'Department', 'Employee', 'Date'])
        .unstack(['Store', 'Department', 'Employee']).fillna(0))
Out[1]: 
Store      Store1                Store2                          Store3       \
Department   dep1      dep2        dep1           dep2             dep1        
Employee     aemp bemp cemp demp   aemp eemp femp cemp demp gemp   bemp eemp   
Date                                                                           
2020-08-03    1.0  1.0  2.0  3.0    1.0  1.0  2.0  0.0  1.0  1.0    2.0  1.0   
2020-08-10    1.0  1.0  0.0  4.0    1.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0    1.0  1.0   

Store            
Department dep2  
Employee   demp  
Date             
2020-08-03  1.0  
2020-08-10  1.0
```

Comment: Thank you David.  I have tried both approach and both works as per my requirements.  Thank you so much for your help.  I choose to go with first approach as it would be yield better performance.  Thanks.